# Как настроить констрейнты в XCode что б высота Image была неким процентом от высоты вью

Tags: xcode, swift, constraints

Пытаюсь сделать простенькую карточную игрушку. 
Не могу разобратся с констрейнтами.
Мне нужно что бы карта имела +- одинаковый размер и размещение на экране независимо от девайса, на котором запущена.

Никак не пойму как именно нужно настроить констрейнты что бы вышло так как мне нужно и размещалось +- так же на всех возможных разрешениях экрана.

На юнити сделать то же самое можно одной левой ногой, а сдесь -- ужас какой-то.

Конечно же, я могу сделать то что хочу просто програмно. Но, это, ведь, не правильный выход.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вам надо, чтоб высота вью всегда была один и тот же процент от высоты родителя, или какого-то указанного вью?

Comment: родителя. В даном случае родителем является ViewController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делаю по памяти, могу что то забыть, но примерно так это происходит:

Выбираете два вью, которые вам надо, и задаете им констрейнт equal height (или equal width по ситуации)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Потом находите только что созданный констрейнт и в нем задаете multiplier. То есть делаете их равными в учетом множителя. Не самый очевидный подход, но что поделать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: очень похоже на то, что это именно то что искал. Сейчас перепроверю и отмечу правильным ответом. Спасибо большое.